# Execute a cursor in Java

Tags: java, sql, cursor

I am trying execute a stored procedure using Java. This SP executes a cursor for deleting registers in my database, but it doesn't work. When the method is executed, it finishes without deleting all of the registers. When I debug my code, it works after adding "thread.sleep(30,000)". Why does my code work after making it sleep?

My code:

**SP (SQL Server) This works well, I tried it individually.**

```
USE [PRUEBA]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_PURGA] (@iDIAS_PURGA INT, @iDIAS_IGNORAR INT)
AS

--DECLARE @iDIAS_PURGA INT = -3, @iDIAS_IGNORAR INT = -3

DECLARE @nvFechaInicio DATETIME, @nvFechaFin DATETIME;
DECLARE @iSeq_num INT;

SELECT @nvFechaFin = DATEADD(DAY,@iDIAS_IGNORAR,GETDATE());
SELECT @nvFechaInicio = DATEADD(DAY,@iDIAS_PURGA+1,@nvFechaFin);

--JL: CREAMOS UN CURSOR PARA ELIMNAR LOS REGISTROS.
DECLARE C_METADATOS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT seq_num FROM TLC_VERINT.dbo.Imported_sessions 
    WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),creation_time,103) BETWEEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@nvFechaInicio,103) AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@nvFechaFin,103)
    AND is_deleted = 1
OPEN C_METADATOS;
FETCH C_METADATOS INTO @iSeq_num;
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
    --ELIMINAMOS REGISTROS DE "Imported_sessions_audio"
    DELETE FROM Imported_sessions_audio WHERE seq_num = @iSeq_num;

    --ELIMINAMOS REGISTROS DE "Imported_sessions"
    DELETE FROM Imported_sessions WHERE seq_num = @iSeq_num;
    --AVANZAMOS AL SIGUIENTE REGISTROS
    FETCH C_METADATOS INTO @iSeq_num;
END
CLOSE C_METADATOS;
DEALLOCATE C_METADATOS;
```

**My Code in Java, i put sleep and works.**

```
@Override
public void fEliminarMetadatos(int iDIAS_PURGA,int iDIAS_IGNORAR) {
    //JL: Variables
    Connection consql = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;

    //JL: Consulta
    try {
        consql = new Conexion().getDBConnectionVerint();
        pstm = consql.prepareStatement("exec [dbo].[SP_PURGA] ?,?");
        pstm.setInt(1, iDIAS_PURGA);
        pstm.setInt(2,iDIAS_IGNORAR);
        //JL: Ejecutamos
        pstm.execute();
        //Thread.sleep(60000);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ERROR ::: Ocurrio un error mientras se ejecutaba ::: [dbo].[SP_PURGA].");
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ERROR ::: "+e);
        Var_runtime.exit(1);
    }finally {
        try {
            if(!consql.isClosed()) {consql.close();}
            if(!pstm.isClosed()) { pstm.close();}
            }catch (Exception e) {
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: Ocurrio un error mientras se trataba de cerrar la conexión para la consulta ::: [dbo].[SP_PURGA].");
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: " + e);
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: El error no es grave, el proceso de extración continuará.");
            }
    }

}
```

How can I make this code work without sleep?

Comment: Are you using transactions? I cannot see a commit in your code. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: @stickybit i not use transaction in this operation, it's just delete registers. Do you think I needed to try commit?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're using here, as your code doesn't show it to me (`Connection` is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html)? And how is it created in `new Conexion().getDBConnectionVerint()`?). But it won't hurt to try to add a line with `consql.commit();` after the line `pstm.execute();`. After all, the worst thing that could happen is that it doesn't help. ;)

Comment: I tried with ´consql.commit();´ and that not works, in ´new Conexion().getDBConnectionVerint()´ i only acquire the conection with the database
´dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONEXION_VERINT, DB_USUARIO_VERINT, BD_PASS_VERINT);´ (The method have much code, but I can not put here.)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find how to make my method work with my cursor from the database, so I simulated a cursor in my code using a transaction as indicated by @stickybit.

That looks like this:

```
@Override
public void fEliminarMetadatos(int iDIAS_PURGA,int iDIAS_IGNORAR) {
    //JL: Variables
    Connection consql = null;
    PreparedStatement pstm1,pstm2,pstm3;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int iContador = 0;
    //JL: Inicializamos pstm's
    pstm1 = pstm2 = pstm3 = null;
    //JL: Consulta
    try {
        consql = new Conexion().getDBConnectionVerint();
        //JL: Cambiamos el commit de la base a false
        consql.setAutoCommit(false);
        pstm1 = consql.prepareStatement("exec [SP_PURGA_GET_SEQNUM] ?,?");
        pstm1.setInt(1, iDIAS_PURGA);
        pstm1.setInt(2,iDIAS_IGNORAR);
        //JL: Ejecutamos
        rs = pstm1.executeQuery();
        //JL: Iteramos sobre el resultado del SP [SP_PURGA_GET_SEQNUM]
        while(rs.next()) {
            iContador ++;
            //JL: eliminamos registro de la tabla Imported_sessions_audio
            pstm2 = consql.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Imported_sessions_audio WHERE seq_num = ?");
            pstm2.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            pstm2.executeUpdate();

            //JL: eliminamos registro de la tabla Imported_sessions
            pstm3 = consql.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM Imported_sessions WHERE seq_num = ?");
            pstm3.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            pstm3.executeUpdate();

            //JL: Confirmamos la ejecución de ambas query's
            consql.commit();

        }
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: INFORMACIÓN ::: Se eliminarón ["+iContador+"] registros de la base de datos.");


    }catch(Exception e) {
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ERROR ::: Ocurrio un error mientras se ejecutaba ::: [dbo].[SP_PURGA_GET_SEQNUM].");
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ERROR ::: "+e);
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ERROR ::: Ocurrio un error grave al ejecutar el proceso de purga, revise los mensajes anteriores a este para mayor información.");
        new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: INFORMACIÓN ::: El proceso de purga finalizó.");
        new CrearLog().archivoLog(":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        Var_runtime.exit(1);
    }finally {
        try {
            if(!consql.isClosed()) {consql.close();}
            if(!pstm1.isClosed()) { pstm1.close();}
            if(!pstm2.isClosed()) { pstm2.close();}
            if(!pstm3.isClosed()) { pstm3.close();}
            }catch (Exception e) {
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: Ocurrio un error mientras se trataba de cerrar la conexión para la consulta ::: [dbo].[SP_PURGA_GET_SEQNUM].");
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: " + e);
                new CrearLog().archivoLog("::: ADVERTENCIA ::: El error no es grave, el proceso de extración continuará.");
            }
    }

}
```

That works for me. If anyone have any idea how do this code better I read them.